# How to get the phase of a 2D sine wave?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, phase, 2d

I am trying to find the phase of a generic 2D sine wave with the 2D FFT. The formula for the phase is **arctan(im/re)**. So I made 22 sine waves with phases ranging from 0 to 2 pi (by cropping the original sine wave at varying y-coordinates) and looped over those with this code:

```
for i in range(22):
inputWave = imread("cropped/croppd"+str(i)+".png")
ffted = fftshift(fft2(inputWave))

x = findPeak(inputWave)[0]
y = findPeak(inputWave)[1]

re = np.real(ffted[x,y])
im = np.imag(ffted[x,y])

phase = np.arctan(im/re)
print(phase)
```

findPeak() is just a simple function to find the location of the frequency point on the fft spectrum, I dont think its relevant here.

real + imaginary part of the first wave: (1.2748466384383707e-13+5.047474910793737e-14j)

The output phases are extremely close together:
0.376991118430776,
0.376991118430776,
0.3769911184307758,
etc.

I dont understand why, I was expecting the angle to shift from 0 to 2pi, just like in the input. Could someone please enlighten me? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Here is the image I used and the code to slice it

[image]

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

im = Image.open(r"90.png")
width, height = im.size

#dimensions of the image
left = 0
top = 0
right = height/2
bottom = height/2
 


for i in range(22):
    img = im.crop((0,2*i,height/4,height/4+2*i))
    img.save("uncropped/uncropped"+str(i)+".png")
```

Comment: Could you upload the image?

Comment: I did! I used a simple 90° sine wave for testing, which you could downgrade/project it to 1D, but for waves with an angle you would need 2 of such 1D waves